# Can I use CoreMIDI without Objective C (just C or C++)?

Tags: c++, c, cocoa, coremidi

I'm having a devil of a time finding out whether I can make a simple midi output layer using Coremidi *without* using Objective-C. The app is a QT desktop app in C++, and I want to keep OS specific things to a minimum and localized to just some output modules.  Timing and latency is crucial so I'd like the midi output layer to be as close to the metal as possible. I'm getting bad sync latency when using PortMidi, and though I'd find out if it improves with CoreMIDI directly. If someone can tell me whether this is possible, and if so point me at an example, that would be luverly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CoreMIDI's API is plain old C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CACoreMIDIRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002091).  You don't need Objective-C or C++.

(It can of course be used directly from Objective-C or C++ code, if you want to, though.)

Comment: Thanks Kurt, guess I'll just experiment converting Objective-C examples into C.

Comment: I'd point you at an example if I knew of one! There was the old "Echo.cpp" that came with the developer tools, 10 years ago, but it wasn't very comprehensive, and I can't find it anymore.

Comment: @IainDuncan Have a look at PGMIDI: http://goodliffe.blogspot.com/2011/02/pgmidi-updated.html. It's an ObjC wrapper around the API. Sounds backwards to recommend that, but it's an easy read and will help you piece it together. CoreMIDI is dead fast so if you use it right you shouldn't have any performance issues.